# JMESPath query for nested array structures

Tags: arrays, json, multidimensional-array, aws-cli, jmespath

I have the following data structure as a result of aws logs get-query-results:

```
    {
    "status": "Complete", 
    "statistics": {
        "recordsMatched": 2.0, 
        "recordsScanned": 13281.0, 
        "bytesScanned": 7526096.0
    }, 
    "results": [
        [
            {
                "field": "time", 
                "value": "2019-01-31T21:53:01.136Z"
            }, 
            {
                "field": "requestId", 
                "value": "a9c233f7-0b1b-3326-9b0f-eba428e4572c"
            }, 
            {
                "field": "logLevel", 
                "value": "INFO"
            }, 
            {
                "field": "callerId", 
                "value": "a9b0f9c2-eb42-3986-33f7-8e450b1b72cf"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "field": "time", 
                "value": "2019-01-25T13:13:01.062Z"
            }, 
            {
                "field": "requestId", 
                "value": "a4332628-1b9b-a9c2-0feb-0cd4a3f7cb63"
            }, 
            {
                "field": "logLevel", 
                "value": "INFO"
            }, 
            {
                "field": "callerId", 
                "value": "a9b0f9c2-eb42-3986-33f7-8e450b1b72cf"
            }
        ],
      ]
    }
```

The AWS CLI support JMESPath language for filtering output. I need to apply a query string, to filter among the returned "results" the objects that contain the "callerId" as a "field", retrieve the "value" property and obtain the following output:

```
    [
      {
       callerId: "a9b0f9c2-eb42-3986-33f7-8e450b1b72cf"
      },
      {
       callerId: "a9b0f9c2-eb42-3986-33f7-8e450b1b72cf"
      }
    ]
```

The first step I do is flatter the results array with the query string: `results[]`

This will get read of the other root properties (status, statistics) and return only one big array with all of the {field: ..., value: ...} alike objects. But after this I can't manage to properly filter for those objects that match field=="callerId". I tried, among others, the following expressions without success:

```
'results[][?field=="callerId"]'
'results[][*][?field=="callerId"]'
'results[].{ callerId: @[?field=="callerId"].value }'
```

I'm not an expert in JMESPath and I was doing the tutorials of the jmespath.org site but couldn't manage to make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: delete the last comma, if you place your json in the JMES Path tester the code would not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jq is a good thing because it's more complete language, but if you want to do it with JMES Path here the solution:

`results[*][?field=='callerId'].{callerId: value}[]`

to get:

```
[
  {
    "callerId": "a9b0f9c2-eb42-3986-33f7-8e450b1b72cf"
  },
  {
    "callerId": "a9b0f9c2-eb42-3986-33f7-8e450b1b72cf"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce fully since I don't have the same logs in my log stream but I was able to do this using jq and putting the sample JSON object in a file

`cat sample_output.json | jq '.results[][] | select(.field=="callerId") | .value'`

**OUTPUT**:

```
"a9b0f9c2-eb42-3986-33f7-8e450b1b72cf"
"a9b0f9c2-eb42-3986-33f7-8e450b1b72cf"
```

you could pipe the output from the aws cli to jq.

I was able to get pretty close with the native JMESPath query and using the built in editor in this site
http://jmespath.org/examples.html#filtering-and-selecting-nested-data

```
results[*][?field==`callerId`][]
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[
  {
    "field": "callerId",
    "value": "a9b0f9c2-eb42-3986-33f7-8e450b1b72cf"
  },
  {
    "field": "callerId",
    "value": "a9b0f9c2-eb42-3986-33f7-8e450b1b72cf"
  }
]
```

but I'm not sure how to get `callerId` to be the key and the value to be the value from another key.

Comment: thanks @jmp, at some point I got something very similar but unfortunately the requirements asked me for JMESPath only.